# How do I store information from methods to be used in another session?

Tags: java

So I'm making a program that will store the meetings I've had with some kids I'm tutoring. It'll keep tabs on the meeting times, discussions, and how many hours I've done. I know how to write all the methods to do that, but my issue is that the program will only hold that information for the session that the program is open... how would I go about storing this information and accessing it after the program is closed and opened again?

This is some excerpts from a test score keeper program I did in java class that has this same issue...

```
    public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int test1;
    private int test2;
    private int test3;

    public Student() {
        name = "";
        test1 = 0;
        test2 = 0;
        test3 = 0;
    }
    public Student(String nm, int t1, int t2, int t3){
        name = nm;
        test1 = t1;
        test2 = t2;
        test3 = t3;
    }
    public Student(Student s){
        name = s.name;
        test1 = s.test1;
        test2 = s.test2;
        test3 = s.test3;
    }
public void setName(String nm){
    name = nm;
}
public String getName (){
    return name;
}
public void setScore (int i, int score){
    if (i == 1) test1 = score;
    else if (i == 2) test2 = score;
    else test3 = score;
}
public int getScore (int i){
    if (i == 1)         return test1;
    else if (i == 2)    return test2;
    else                return test3;
}
public int getAverage(){
    int average;
    average = (int) Math.round((test1 + test2 + test3) / 3.0);
    return average;
}
public int getHighScore(){
    int highScore;
    highScore = test1;
    if (test2 > highScore) highScore = test2;
    if (test3 > highScore) highScore = test3;
    return highScore;
}

public String toString(){
    String str;
    str =   "Name:      " + name    + "\n" +    //\n makes a newline
            "Test 1:    " + test1   + "\n" +
            "Test 2:    " + test2   + "\n" +
            "Test 3:    " + test3   + "\n" +
            "Average:   " + getAverage();
    return str;
}
}
```

Comment: Assuming you can write data someplace, you might want to just write your data to file locally. Check out [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).

Comment: @MarsAtomic Oh no, I know how to write things to files and access the lines, I was just wondering if there was an easier way to do that. Or an efficient method at accessing large bits of information about 1 particular thing (i.e. one student's: times met, details, time spent, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, I had to write to the lowest common denominator, since I didn't have any real indication of your skill/experience. If you want something powerful and relatively efficient, I'd look into a [SQLite3](http://www.sqlite.org/) database. Very compact RDBMS that takes surprisingly little space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is not too big or complicated - something that you could save in a Rolodex in days gone by - you can save it to a file. Add methods to your class that will format the data properly and write it to a given `OutputStream` or `Writer` or whatever. And a method that will read it back.

To write to the file, add an option "save" in your program menu, and when it's chosen, open a file, iterate through your data, and call the saving method for each of your object.

To read from the file, add an option "load" in your program menu, and when it's chosen, open a file, and use your method of reading for each object.

The method for reading can be a static method in the class, that will first see if there are any data in the file and if it can read them properly, and only if it did, will create an object and return it (otherwise return null). There are other options, but this is the one that most encapsulates the needs of the object.

There is also an option to serialize and deserialize each object and put it in an object stream.

If the data is complicated, and there are many objects with various relations between them, you should use a database. This will require learning some database design and SQL.

To demonstrate the file reading/writing idea, add to your `Student` class:

```
public void save(PrintWriter outfile) {
    outfile.format("%s|%d|%d|%d%n", name, test1, test2, test3);
}
```

This will write a line with the fields separated by "|" (vertical bar). Of course, you'll have to make sure none of the student names has a vertical bar in it. So you'll need to modify your 4-parameter constructor and your setter:

```
public Student(String nm, int t1, int t2, int t3) {
    name = nm.replaceAll("\\|", "");
    test1 = t1;
    test2 = t2;
    test3 = t3;
}

public void setName(String nm) {
    name = nm.replaceAll("\\|", "");
}
```

Now, to read the file, we add a static method:

```
public static Student load(BufferedReader infile) throws IOException {
    String line;
    line = infile.readLine();

    // Check if we reached end of file
    if (line == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // Split the fields by the "|", and check that we have no less than 4
    // fields.
    String[] fields = line.split("\\|");
    if (fields.length < 4) {
        return null;
    }

    // Parse the test scores
    int[] tests = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        try {
            tests[i] = Integer.parseInt(fields[i + 1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // The field is not a number. Return null as we cannot parse
            // this line.
            return null;
        }
    }

    // All checks done, data ready, create a new student record and return
    // it
    return new Student(fields[0], tests[0], tests[1], tests[2]);
}
```

You can see that this is more complicated, because you need to check that everything is OK at every step. In any case when things are not OK, we return `null` but of course, you can decide to just display a warning and read the next line. You'll have to return null when there are no more lines, though.

So, assuming we have a `List<Student> students`, here is how we write it to a file. I just chose "students.txt" but you can specify a full path leading where you want it. Note how I'm making a backup of the old file before I open the new file. If something goes wrong, at least you have the previous version of the file.

```
    File f = new File("students.txt");
    if (f.exists()) {
        File backup = new File("students.bak");
        if ( ! f.renameTo(backup) ) {
            System.err.println( "Could not create backup.");
            return;
        }
        f = new File("students.txt");
    }

    try ( PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(f);) {

        for (Student student : students) {
            student.save(outFile);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not open file for writing.");
        return;
    }
```

After you do this, if you look for the file "students.txt", you will see the records you wrote in it.

How about reading it? Assume we have an empty `students` list (not null!):

```
    try ( BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
        Student student;
        while ( ( student = Student.load(inFile)) != null) {
            students.add(student);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println( "Could not open file for reading.");
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println( "An error occured while reading from the file.");
    }
```

Having done this, you can check your `students` list, and unless there were errors in the file, all your records will be there.

This is a demonstration, of course. You may want to read into some other collection or instead of printing an error and returning do something else. But it should give you the idea.

Comment: I like this idea. So for each student then, in this case, would I need to make a new text file for them?

Comment: Only if you want to have as many files are there are students. I was thinking more about opening the file, and then calling each of your student objects' `save` method, passing the `Writer` or `Stream` object as a parameter.

Comment: I've edited my answer and added code to demonstrate the principle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use db4o for persisting your data. Its an object-database with a spimple api to use. You can store java object read or delete them..

Download it here [DB4O](ftp://ftp.versant.com/po/db4o/production/db4o-8.0.276.16149-java.zip)

And use the snippets of this tutorial (GER):[Tutorial in German](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Db4o)

Here is an example:

[image: Projectstructure]

and Code:

```
package db4o.example;


public class Student {

    String name;

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student Name: " + name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


package db4o.example;

import java.util.List;

import com.db4o.Db4oEmbedded;
import com.db4o.ObjectContainer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile("F:\\studentDB");
        saveExample(db);
        readAllExample(db);
        readExample(db);
        deleteAllExample(db);
        db.close();
    }

    private static void deleteAllExample(ObjectContainer db) {
        System.out.println("DeleteAllExample Example:");
        List<Student> allStudents =readAllExample(db);
        for (Student student : allStudents) {
            db.delete(student);
        }
        db.commit();
    }

    private static List<Student> readAllExample(ObjectContainer db) {
        System.out.println("ReadAllExample Example:");
        List<Student> allStudents = db.query(Student.class);
        System.out.println("Count: " + allStudents.size());
        for (Student student : allStudents) {
            System.out.println(student);
        }
        return allStudents;
    }

    private static void readExample(ObjectContainer db) {
        System.out.println("ReadExample Example:");
        Student queryStudent = new Student("Max Mustermann");
        // Gets all Students named Max Mustermann
        List<Student> students = db.queryByExample(queryStudent);
        System.out.println("Count: " + students.size());
        for (Student student : students) {
            System.out.println(student);
        }
    }

    private static void saveExample(ObjectContainer db) {
        System.out.println("Save Example:");
        Student myStudent = new Student("Max Mustermann");
        db.store(myStudent);
        db.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay..i should say that object databases compared to relation databases are much less performant. But if you know you have not a huge amount of data, this is a nice thing

Comment: My only issue with this, because I assume this would work with flying colors of course, is that I have no experience with databases. I barely started programming back in September and only have experience in Java >.<

Comment: There is no need of experience. The internals are completly hidden and if you dont need to build indices for greater performance for millions of datasets.. you kan simply open the data base and use .set(object)  or .get(object)  and magicaly it works ;)

Comment: I just have no idea to like, move things I need written from Java into this "DB4O" thing. Or on a similar note, move things from "DB4O' to my Java interface. I want to keep this whole project Console-Based by the way, since I will be the only one using it.

Comment: In Java you have Objects like a instance of Student and if you want to save the complete object with all attributes you only have to say  db.set(myStudentInstance); in your java code.  If you want to get all Students with Name "Max" You can instantiate an Student set the Name attribute and call db.get(studentTemplateObj);  This is how you move data between java and db4o.

Comment: =~= I'm so sorry I'm lost. I just don't know where to put this file or anything. I'd just rather keep this all in java hun...

Comment: edited my answer maybe this helps. U only need to copy the -all-java5.jar to your classpath. (As a hint on my computer the Databasefile cannot be on theSystem partition because security reasons)